# phpunit: get more debugging information when I get an error

Tags: phpunit

I'm interested in getting more dubugging information when I get an error.

Now I'm getting something like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyFirm\PlatformBundle\Entity\Review\LandmarkReviewRepository' not found in /home/me/mf/myfirm2/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php on line 577

Fatal error: Class 'MyFirm\PlatformBundle\Entity\Review\LandmarkReviewRepository' not found in /home/me/mf/myfirm2/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php on line 577
```

but it's not enough for me, I want to know the some more functions or files where called right before that error happens.

Any idea?

phpunit 3.5.14

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install xdebug: it gives you better stacktraces.

Comment: It might seem like a short answer but imho it's all there is to say about that :) +1 from me (yesterday)